# How can i add the items to the List only 24 times and not 96?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
List<Vector2> uvs = new List<Vector2>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        uvs.Add(new Vector2(0, 1));
        uvs.Add(new Vector2(0, 0));
        uvs.Add(new Vector2(1, 1));
        uvs.Add(new Vector2(1, 0));
    }
    Vector2[] uv = uvs.ToArray();
```

There are 24 vertices but the way i'm doing the loop the array uv contains 96 items. What i want to do is instead doing:

```
Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[]
        {
            //Front face// 0,0 bottom left, 1,1 top right//
            new Vector2(0,1),
            new Vector2(0,0),
            new Vector2(1,1),
            new Vector2(1,0),

            new Vector2(0,1),
            new Vector2(0,0),
            new Vector2(1,1),
            new Vector2(1,0),

            new Vector2(0,1),
            new Vector2(0,0),
            new Vector2(1,1),
            new Vector2(1,0),

            new Vector2(0,1),
            new Vector2(0,0),
            new Vector2(1,1),
            new Vector2(1,0),

            new Vector2(0,1),
            new Vector2(0,0),
            new Vector2(1,1),
            new Vector2(1,0),

            new Vector2(0,1),
            new Vector2(0,0),
            new Vector2(1,1),
            new Vector2(1,0)
        };
```

To do it in a shorter code.
The problem is that the loop i did is not right and the code is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate up to the `vertices.Length / 4`. Change your `for` loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length / 4; i++)
{
    uvs.Add(new Vector2(0, 1));
    uvs.Add(new Vector2(0, 0));
    uvs.Add(new Vector2(1, 1));
    uvs.Add(new Vector2(1, 0));
}
```

It will iterate 6 times and add 6 x 4 = 24 items.

Comment: Alternatively, `for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i+=4)`